# How can I switch the yes and no blocks of hikers group?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have created pivot table using data frame.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 6))

df2.plot.barh(stacked = True,
            ax = ax,
            width = 0.5,
            edgecolor = "black")
plt.xlabel('Percentage (%)')
ax.set_yticklabels(['Non-Hikers','Hikers'], rotation=0)
```

Below is pivot table

```
Wants_hiking    False   True
Likes_hiking        
False           63.64   36.36
True            26.97   73.03
```

I've created horizontal stacked bar chart.

I want to just switch the yes and no blocks of hikers group.

I've created horizontal stacked bar chart.

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
(df1.sort_index(ascending=False)
    .plot
    .barh(stacked=True,
          ax=ax,
          width=0.5,
          edgecolor="black"))
plt.xlabel('Percentage (%)')
ax.set_yticklabels(['Non-Hikers', 'Hikers'], rotation=0)
```

Comment: I tried the code given by you, but the expected output should be in below manner:  1.the hikers bar should be at the top and the non-hikers bar needs to be at the bottom. 2. the greatest value (i.e yes with 73.03) of the hikers bar needs to be on the left side of the graph.